# how to pass ajax data to woocommerce filter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

How could I pass Ajax value form order to woocommerce_add_cart_item_data filter?

I've tried doing this, but it's not working. It seems that $_data gets set after woocommerce_add_cart_item_data is initialized. How could I fix it?

```
class Insertion {

    private $_data = null;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_ss_AjaxData', array($this, 'ss_AjaxData') );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ss_AjaxData', array($this, 'ss_AjaxData') );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array($this, 'add_cart_item_custom_data_vase'), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', array($this, 'get_cart_items_from_session'), 1, 3 );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', array($this, 'get_item_data'),10,2);
    }

    function add_cart_item_custom_data_vase( $cart_item_meta ) {
        if($this->_data != null) {
            $cart_item_meta['test_field'] = $this->_data;
        }

        return $cart_item_meta; 
    }

    function get_cart_items_from_session( $cart_item_meta, $values ) {
        if( isset( $values['test_field'] ) ) {
            $cart_item_meta['test_field'] = $values['test_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item_meta;
    }
    public function get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {
        if( isset( $cart_item['test_field'] ) ) {
            $other_data['test_field'] = array(
                'name' => $cart_item['test_field'], 
                'value' =>$cart_item['test_field']
            );
        }

        return $other_data;
}
    function ss_AjaxData() {
        if(isset($_REQUEST)) {
            $data = $_REQUEST['ss_html'];
            $this->_data = wp_filter_nohtml_kses($data);
            echo $this->_data;  
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

FIX (if someone would face same problem):
Found a way how to fix it. Instead of using private variable I used session. Extend code with a few fixes.

```
    function ss_AjaxData() {
        if(isset($_REQUEST)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['test_field'] = $_REQUEST['ss_html']; 
        }
        exit();
    }

    function add_cart_item_custom_data_vase( $cart_item_meta ) {
        session_start();
        $cart_item_meta['test_field'] = $_SESSION['test_field'];

        return $cart_item_meta; 
    }
```